# VueJS/Vue-router and facebook page integration

Tags: facebook, facebook-javascript-sdk, vuejs2, vue-router

I'm using VueJS and vue-router with webpack+vue-loader.

I want to include a facebook page on a vue so I add in created() event

```
        (function(d, s, id) {
          var js, fjs = d.getElementsByTagName(s)[0];
          if (d.getElementById(id)) return;
          js = d.createElement(s); js.id = id;
          js.src = "//connect.facebook.net/fr_FR/sdk.js#xfbml=1&version=v2.6";
          fjs.parentNode.insertBefore(js, fjs);
        }(document, 'script', 'facebook-jssdk'));
```

and on my template tag

```
<div class="fb-page" ...>
```

but this work only the first time I load the vue. If I go on another page of my website and return back on this page, the facebook page won't load.

I've experienced the same issue with google maps who showed up only the first time. I used vue2-google-maps module to make it works

Thanks